# unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, sdk

Actually i am using push notification for my app but i am getting these warnings 
"

**Warning**: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in /home/safeapp/public_html/QuickCheck/PushServiceTest.php on line 13

**Warning**: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/safeapp/public_html/QuickCheck/PushServiceTest.php on line 52

**Warning**: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/safeapp/public_html/QuickCheck/PushServiceTest.php on line 52

**Warning**: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/safeapp/public_html/QuickCheck/PushServiceTest.php on line 58
"

i am pretty sure that code is ok and might be possible that there is some server functionality missing.i have checked that  open ssl support is enabled.
Please help me and any small help will be highly appreciable.
Thanku

Comment: it's not working for me neither today

Answer (score 0):

Hosting will have to enable  “socket client” through .htaccess file. or enable complete open ssl support.
Anyone can give their comment on this answer.